# Error in printing elements of an Multidimensional Array (Java)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

I want to print all the elements of the matrix. But the complier throws "Cannot find symbol" error. I want to know the exact problem and its remedy.

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] matrix = {
            {3, 2, 1},
            {3, 2, 1},
            {5, 5, 8}
    };
    
    for (int[] i : matrix);
        for ( int j : i);
    System.out.println("At Row "+ i + " at column" + j + " = " + matrix[i][j]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. You need to iterate over the indexes and not the objects
2. You have a ";" where you should have an opening brace ("{")

```java
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i += 1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j += 1) {
                System.out.println("At Row "+ i + " at column" + j + " = " + matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
```

```
At Row 0 at column0 = 3                                                         
At Row 0 at column1 = 2                                                         
At Row 0 at column2 = 1                                                         
At Row 1 at column0 = 3                                                         
At Row 1 at column1 = 2                                                         
At Row 1 at column2 = 1                                                         
At Row 2 at column0 = 5                                                         
At Row 2 at column1 = 5                                                         
At Row 2 at column2 = 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Allen already point out your mistakes.
If you want to achieve the same with foreach loop :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = { { 3, 2, 1 }, { 3, 2, 1 }, { 5, 5, 8 } };

        for (int[] i : matrix) { 
            System.out.print("Row --> ");
            for (int j : i) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```